# JS Dice - Assigning Math.random value to an html image using if condition

Tags: javascript, html, image, if-statement, random

Hello i'm using Javascript to create a random dice output (from 1-6) including an image of the dice side.
The mathRandomDice function is working fine but my 'if' condition which assigning it to the image is not...
My goal is to assign the Math.random value to an image.

```
function mathRandomDice() {
    document.getElementById("dice").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 

}

var x = mathRandomDice;

  if (x = 1) {
            d.innerHTML = '<img src=https://image.ibb.co/cQKOhc/dice1.png>';
    }
```

```js
function mathRandomDice() {
    document.getElementById("dice").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 

}
```

```css
  body {
    text-align:center;}


/* button */

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

button:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

button:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
 <h5> Press the button for a random dice number<h5>
    <span id="yournum"></span>
   <p id="dice"></p>
<button onclick="mathRandomDice()">Roll The Dice</button>
<br><br>
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cQKOhc/dice1.png" alt="1" class="center">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cmyG2c/dice2.png" alt="2" class="center">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/bPNyFx/dice3.png" alt="3" class="center">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/fmkJFx/dice4.png" alt="4" class="center">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/d6D5vx/dice5.png" alt="5" class="center">
   <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nFqkvx/dice6.png" alt="6" class="center">
```

Comment: How does `x` get set? Is your function missing something? Maybe `return` to you code and review `mathRandomDice()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is really simple..

My friend Corristo was right that i wrote the veriable assignment wrong "(x = 1)" insted of "(x == 1)"

You have to put the random result  on the function like this:

img.src = "dice"+ random + ".jpg"

So by that you can load the correct image for the random number

random == 1
"dice"+ random + ".jpg" = dice1.jpg

random == 2
"dice"+ random + ".jpg" = dice2.jpg

and so on..

Answer (score 1):

a single `=` is an assignment operator. For comparison use `==` or `===`. This should work:

```
if (x == 1) {
    d.innerHTML = '<img src=https://image.ibb.co/cQKOhc/dice1.png>';
}
```